# Formula for the sum of the n terms of a geometric progression doesn't give the same result and a direct sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My professor taught us that when you have a convergent geometric progression you can use

$$\sum_{n=d}^\infty a_n = \frac{a_d}{1-r}$$

where r is the ratio and $-1 < r <1$.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the formula because I thought it was supposed to add the n terms starting from the first one but when I try that with $a_n = (-1/2)^n$ (exercise given by my professor) where the ratio is -1/2 and the sum (using the given formula) with d = 3 is -1/12. However when I do $a_1+a_2+a_3$ it doesn't give me this value. I figure what this formula really does is sum all the terms of the sequence except for the ones until d. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the first $n$ terms would be $\sum_{j=1}^na_j$. The notation in your question means $$\sum_{n=d}^\infty a_n=a_d+a_{d+1}+\dots .$$